# Error occurs in when click on a button in a tabbed activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs

I use four tabs in my android application. An image button is in one tab activity and when I click that button I need to go to another activity which is not a tab activity. I tried a lot to do this, but once I click on the tab my app has stopped work. Please if someone could help me to solve this issue. I really appreciate your help.

This is FirstFragment.java file. I use image button in this activity and after click that button need to go to another activity.

```
package com.example.user.application001.fragmentspkg;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import com.example.user.application001.Invoice;
import com.example.user.application001.R;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public FirstFragment(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

        ImageButton fabImageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_image_button);
        fabImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Users.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_image_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_shape"
        android:src="@drawable/plusbtn"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your error log

Comment: post your xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using layout of `fragment_second` in  `fragment_first` change it

use this

```
View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
```

instead of this

```
View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
```